# Mysql query isn't working especially the Scan() method

Tags: mysql, go

I am trying the print the struct variable but it's returning the zero value where I want an actual database row value.

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

type Users struct {
    Id         int
    Username   string
    Password   string
    Email      string
    First_name string
    Last_name  string
    Created_at time.Time
    Super_user bool
}

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:Megamind@1@(127.0.0.1:3306)/note?parseTime=true")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Couldn't connect to the database")
    }

    var user Users
    row := db.QueryRow("select password from users where username=$1", "someone")
    row.Scan(&user.Id, &user.Username, &user.Password, &user.Email, &user.First_name, &user.Last_name, &user.Created_at, &user.Super_user)
    fmt.Println(user)
}
```

Database:

```
mysql> select * from users;
+----+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+------------+-----------+---------------------+------------+
| id | username      | password                                                     | email                     | first_name | last_name | created_at          | super_user |
+----+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+------------+-----------+---------------------+------------+
|  3 | someone       | $2a$10$a0g.eIGEHoVnD/s55YCePeL5BxCPYDF58nP2gb.TmYKwCuV5E7gP. | abc@gmail.com | NULL       | NULL      | 2020-06-22 01:24:43 |       NULL |
|  4 | oneanother    | $2a$10$VMo4iuvruCA/yQlkfMI2QOMWo2H2jIiyyoYprKQtQMT4U7UWb78CS | one@one.com               | NULL       | NULL      | 2020-06-22 01:26:48 |       NULL |
|  5 | alpha | $2a$10$oD0YKBkTvJQVPF4rilEVYemjRtwNF3ATGlVLUOVGZzR5lNx5fRl3. | alpha@gmail.com   | NULL       | NULL      | 2020-06-22 01:45:34 |       NULL |
+----+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+------------+-----------+---------------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Output:

```
(base) [dave@192 test]$ go run main.go 
{0      0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC false}
```

Comment: Scan returns an error which will tell you what is wrong. In case it's too cryptic: it probably says that while you're requesting in the query only 1 column (the `password`), you are providing a bunch of destination fields to scan whose count is certainly more than 1. Put another way, you MUST provide the same number of arguments to scan as the number of columns returned by the query... anyway the main takeaway is that you should not ignore errors, not "never" but probably 99% of the time.

Comment: ... actually the error probably says that `$1` is not a "thing" since you're using mysql, you need to use `?` for the parameter references. `$N` is a postgres specific "thing" which, if not supported by the driver, will not be automatically translated into `?`. But, even after you fix that, you would still receive the error hinted to in the first comment if you use different numbers of columns/scan args.

Comment: Don't ignore errors

Comment: I'll bite.  Why is this tagged `gopherjs`?

Comment: Doesn't SQL need a semicolon at the end of a query?